# How can I get rid of the new line created after this bash command?

Tags: python, linux, bash

I'm trying to store the result of this BASH command in a variable:

```
 localip = subprocess.check_output(["ifconfig | grep 'inet addr' | cut -d ':' -f2 | grep 'Bcast' | cut -d ' ' -f1"], shell=True)
```

but if I print local ip it always have a new line:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Documents $ python change.py
192.168.1.6

pi@raspberrypi:~/Documents $
```

Which is of course not what I need, so I've tried something like this:

```
localip[0].replace("\n", "")
```

or simply

```
localip.replace("\n", "")
```

but still no good....does anyone know of to get rid of the new created line? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the meantime I solved in that way:

```
localip = subprocess.check_output(["ifconfig | grep 'inet addr' | cut -d ':' -f2 | grep 'Bcast' | cut -d ' ' -f1 | tr -d '\n'"], shell=True)
```

piping a `tr -d '\n'` at the end.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't posted the code that actually prints `localip` but one possible reason is that you don't print the return value of [`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace). [`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) doesn't mutate the existing string but it returns a new copy instead.